Select rows that contain a specific dropdown value
I have the following Google Spreadsheet file:
A "People" sheet:

and a "Projects" sheet:

As you can see, I've added a "Projects" dropdown to the People sheet using data validation so I can indicate what projects each person is on.
Now what I want is to have some kind of "back reference" in the Projects sheet, so I can see all the people that are on each project, using the data from the People sheet.
On the second screenshot, you can see one of my failed attempts using the following formula : =TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; QUERY(People!$A$2:$B; "SELECT A WHERE B CONTAINS '" & A2 & "'")). The problems are that 1) an error #N/A is returned for projects that have nobody on it, and 2) most importantly some people are incorrectly matched. For example, for Project 1, CALLISON Edgar is matched while he's not on the project, probably because his project, 31, has a 1 in it and thus is matched by the formula.
How I can I fix this?

You can use IFNA to hide the error and MATCHES with \b word boundaries instead of CONTAINS.
=IFNA(TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; QUERY(People!$A$2:$B; "SELECT A WHERE B MATCHES '.*\b" & A2 & "\b.*'")))


From the documentation: "Note that this is not a global search, so where country matches 'an' will not match 'Canada'." — add leading and trailing wildcards?

Awesome!! Thank you!! And thanks for explaining.

Another Option: Use Filter
You may use the following formula:
=BYROW(TOCOL(A2:A;1);LAMBDA(y; JOIN(", ";TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FILTER(People!$A$2:$A;BYROW(People!$B$2:$B;LAMBDA(w;OR(BYCOL(split(w;",");LAMBDA(x;x=y)))))))))))

Input:
For the input, I added SMITH Jack to project ID 8 to test for multiple entries.

Output:

Miscellaneous Info:
If you just want a formula per row, you may remove the first Byrow function as seen below:
=JOIN(", ";TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FILTER(People!$A$2:$A;BYROW(People!$B$2:$B;LAMBDA(w;OR(BYCOL(split(w;",");LAMBDA(x;x=A2)))))))))




Thank you! I had to replace commas , by semi-colons ; to fix formula error, unfortunately it still doesn't work... I have a #REF! error. It only works for CALLISON.

The second, simplified, formula that you gave works though :)

Oh, you are using EU format. Let me fix that real quick.

When I set my spreadsheet to an EU locale, my formula was automatically updated to EU format. Kindly check if it works now. You do not need to drag down the first formula as it uses a byrow function.

I think this easiest to do with filter() and regexmatch(), like this:
=ifna(join(", "; filter(People!A$2:A; regexmatch(People!B$2:B; "\b" & A2 & "\b"))))

See filter() and regexmatch().

Thanks for letting me know! I like QUERY() though because it allows me to customize the display of the selected values :) and in an SQL-like way which is an advantage when you're a developer. But it's cool to know that there are other ways!

Please edit the question and add all relevant details there.

The question is already complete, I was just reflecting on your answer. Anyway it can still be useful in other cases.

When you judge answers using criteria that's not shown in the question, subsequent readers may get confused why you accepted one particular answer that has no obvious benefit other than meeting those hidden criteria.

You're right, but I did mention QUERY() in my question, so it wasn't a hidden criteria, although I didn't explain why I was using it. And the accepted answer understood it perfectly. Now also keep in mind that not everyone has enough knowledge in a given area, like me with Google Sheets, to be able to describe all the criteria at a level so precise that only one answer is possible. When you're a beginner at something, you don't even really know what you need. That's why you ask for help. Please kindly remember that.
